# Parsing xml in nodejs and reconstructing back to xml

Tags: node.js, xml

I am working with Nodejs to accept xml from http and forward it as xml to a tcp server that accpts only xml.
The xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Iso8583PostXml>
      <MsgType>0100</MsgType>
       <Fields>
       <Field_002>5413330089020011</Field_002>
       <Field_003>000000</Field_003>
       <Field_004>000000002000</Field_004>
       <Field_007>0723125622</Field_007>
       <Field_011>148893</Field_011>
       <Field_012>125622</Field_012>
       <Field_013>0723</Field_013>
       <Field_014>2512</Field_014>
       <Field_018>4111</Field_018>
       <Field_022>14111</Field_022>
       <Field_023>003</Field_023>
       <Field_025>00</Field_025>
       <Field_026>12</Field_026>
       <Field_035>5413330089020011D2512601079360805F</Field_035>
       <Field_041>3132333435363738</Field_041>
       <Field_042>465726368616E7420312030303</Field_042>
       <Field_043>4D6F6269746C6C20449204B45204B45</Field_043>
       <Field_045>0303030204E4149524F4249204B45204B45</Field_045>
       <Field_049>404</Field_049>
       <Field_123>09010001000105010103040C010001</Field_123>
    </Fields>
</Iso8583PostXml>
```

I have used body express-xml-bodyparser to parse the xml and it gives me this

```
{
    "iso8583postxml": {
       "msgtype": [
         "0100"
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "field_002": [
                "5413330089020011"
            ],
            "field_003": [
                "000000"
            ],
            "field_004": [
                "000000002000"
            ],
            "field_007": [
                "0723125622"
            ],
            "field_011": [
                "148893"
            ],
            "field_012": [
                "125622"
            ],
            "field_013": [
                "0723"
            ],
            "field_014": [
                "2512"
            ],
            "field_018": [
                "4111"
            ],
            "field_022": [
                "14111"
            ],
            "field_023": [
                "003"
            ],
            "field_025": [
                "00"
            ],
            "field_026": [
                "12"
            ],
            "field_035": [
                "5413330089020011D2512601079360805F"
            ],
            "field_041": [
                "3132333435363738"
            ],
            "field_042": [
                "465726368616E7420312030303"
            ],
            "field_043": [
                "4D6F6269746C6C20449204B45204B45"
            ],
            "field_045": [
                "0303030204E4149524F4249204B45204B45"
            ],
            "field_049": [
                "404"
            ],
            "field_123": [
                "09010001000105010103040C010001"
             ]
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

How can i convert this object back to an xml? PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

I have built the xml manually while converting the nested arrays to objects and a assigning in the for loop.
If you have an improvement or efficient way will help.
firstCaps is a function that capitalize the first letter

```
let xml = null;
let items = req.body['iso8583postxml']
    let fields = req.body['iso8583postxml'].fields[0]
    xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    xml +='<Iso8583PostXml>'
    xml += '<Msgtype>'+items['msgtype']+'</Msgtype>>'
    xml += '<Fields>'
    for (let prop in fields) {
        if (fields.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            xml += '<'+firstCaps(prop)+'>' + fields[prop][0] + '</'+firstCaps(prop)+'>' 

        }

    }
    xml += '</Fields>'
    xml +='</Iso8583PostXml>'
```